# Failed to load planning library in MOVEIT motion planning

Tags: ros2, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are doing project on igus robot arm. We have developed URDF package from SW2URDF extension. After that we are trying to integrate it in moveit setup assistant and generated package for moveit_config.

But, we are facing some error as below while launching demo.launch file,

```
[ INFO] [1520952510.319394087]: waitForService: Service [/get_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1520952515.319986595]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group? at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-planning-0.9.11/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp:486
[ INFO] [1520952534.691775951]: No active joints or end effectors found for group ''. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[ INFO] [1520952534.711537925]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'igus_planning' in namespace ''
[ERROR] [1520952564.725922669]: Unable to connect to move_group action server 'move_group' within allotted time (30s)
[ INFO] [1520952564.728670183]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'igus_planning' in namespace ''
[ WARN] [1520952564.779985993]: Interactive marker 'EE:goal_l4' contains unnormalized quaternions. This warning will only be output once but may be true for others; enable DEBUG messages for ros.rviz.quaternions to see more details.
```

It is not showing planning library in moveit*rviz window under motion planning.

Packages for URDF and moveit_config package are in github link below.

https://github.com/npd26/igus

Anyone have idea about what should we do to get planning library?

ROS version : kinetic

Thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285287/failed-to-load-planning-library-in-moveit-motion-planning/) by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been experience when the URDF is highly detailed and takes a while to load such that certain node times out after a period of time. Does your URDF contain detailed meshes?

---

Originally posted by [Levi-Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27969/levi-armstrong/) with karma: 106 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2018-03-13**:
we have 5 links so in total 5 meshes. you can see in github URDF package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
@nnnnn: if you've exported from SolidWorks the STLs are most likely way too detailed. Try subsampling your meshes and see if that works.

For a quick test you could even comment all `visual` elements and see if things start working. If they do, it's the meshes.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2018-03-13**:
ok, we will try and update here.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2018-03-14**:
@gvdhoorn We tried by commenting all visual elements in urdf and generated moveit package but same error is showing while launching demo.launch file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Then it might be that something else is wrong/not working.

Subsampling meshes coming from SolidWorks is most likely a good idea anyway though. And creating separate `collision` meshes (with much lower face and vertex count) is also a good idea.

**Comment by [Levi-Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27969/levi-armstrong/) on 2018-03-14**:
If you run `roslaunch igus_description display.launch` does everything load in rviz?

**Comment by [Levi-Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27969/levi-armstrong/) on 2018-03-14**:
So I just clone your repository and tested things. Your models are to detailed (~25MB each) and the reason commenting out the visual did not work is because you are using the same model for visual and collision. I replace the meshes with boxes and everything works.

**Comment by [Levi-Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27969/levi-armstrong/) on 2018-03-14**:
I recommend decimating the models using Blender or Meshlab. If you required this level of detail you will need to break up the launch sequence yourself so you can wait for certain nodes to fully load before launching other nodes.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:\

> Your models are to detailed (~25MB each)

I cannot upvote this enough. 25MB per mesh is overkill. I just opened one and saw all nuts and bolts in there. That will definitely significantly impact performance.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2018-03-14**:
Ok, now we realized that because of detailed meshes it takes around 5 minutes to completely load the planning library after taking two-three attempts to connect with move_group server. So after that everything is working properly.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2018-03-14**:
But, according to your suggestions we will replace collision meshes with boxes and give you update.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
You don't need to use boxes. You can create convex hulls.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2018-03-15**:
@gvdhoorn @Levi-Armstrong Thank you for your help. We have decimated our meshes using blender and it works very smooth. We can see now planning library without any error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-15**:
If your issue is now resolved, then please tick the checkmark next to Levi's answer to mark this question as answered.